# run query on private function event codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert

I wish to run my second function (insert function) on load of `(client/results)` view.

so when getResults in trigger i wish to also run create function.

```
 private function getResults()
    {
        $data['emailcount'] = $score = $this->actions->getEmailCount();
        $data['sentEmailCount'] = $score = $this->actions->getSentEmailCount();
        $data['score'] = $score = $this->actions->getScore();
        $data['percentile'] = $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
        $data['timespent'] = $this->input->get('time');
//            echo $this->input->get('time');
        return $this->load->view('client/results', $data);
    }

    function create()
    {
        $adddata = array(
            'uniID' => '5',
            'testName' => 'Abintegro E-Tray test',
            'testID' => '99999',
            'total' => '20',
            'userID' => '00000',
            'useInPercentile' => '1',
            'correct' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percent' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percentile' => $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score),
            'dateTaken' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
//            'timeSpent' => $this->input->get('time')

        );
        $this->actions->add_record($adddata);
        $this->index();
    }
```

what I have tried

```
    private function getResults()
    {
        $data['emailcount'] = $score = $this->actions->getEmailCount();
        $data['sentEmailCount'] = $score = $this->actions->getSentEmailCount();
        $data['score'] = $score = $this->actions->getScore();
        $data['percentile'] = $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
        $data['timespent'] = $this->input->get('time');
//            echo $this->input->get('time');
        $this->create();
        return $this->load->view('client/results', $data);
    }
```

but this creates a error

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp64\www\New\system\database\DB_query_builder.php on line 2507

and tried

```
    private function getResults()
    {
        {
            $data['emailcount'] = $score = $this->actions->getEmailCount();
            $data['sentEmailCount'] = $score = $this->actions->getSentEmailCount();
            $data['score'] = $score = $this->actions->getScore();
            $data['percentile'] = $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
            $data['timespent'] = $this->input->get('time');
//            echo $this->input->get('time');
            $this->create();
            return $this->load->view('client/results', $data);
        };
        $this->actions->add_record($adddata);
        $this->index();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private function getResults()
    {
        {
            $data['emailcount'] = $score = $this->actions->getEmailCount();
            $data['sentEmailCount'] = $score = $this->actions->getSentEmailCount();
            $data['score'] = $score = $this->actions->getScore();
            $data['percentile'] = $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
            $data['timespent'] = $this->input->get('time');
//            echo $this->input->get('time');

        };

        $adddata = array(
            'uniID' => '5',
            'testName' => 'Abintegro E-Tray test',
            'testID' => '99999',
            'total' => '20',
            'userID' => '00000',
            'useInPercentile' => '1',
            'correct' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percent' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percentile' => $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score),
            'dateTaken' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
//            'timeSpent' => $this->input->get('time')

        );

        $this->actions->add_record($adddata);
//        $this->index();
        return $this->load->view('client/results', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You got an infinite loop of 2 functions calling each other indefinitely (may be not directly).

In your `getResults()` you call `$this->create();`
check if any of the `create()` calls end up in the `getResults()` if so, you are creating a recursion loop.

Comment: Thanks, Ive fixed it